# Find the name and age of the youngest student who is either a English major or enrolled in a course taught by Ivana Teach

Tags: sql

The schema is as follows:

```
Student(snum: integer primary key, sname: varchar(40), major: varchar(40), level: varchar(40), age: integer)

Faculty (fid: integer primary key, fname: varchar(40), deptid: integer)

Class(name: varchar(40) primary key, meets at: varchar(40), room: varchar(40), fid: integer references faculty)

Enrolled(snum: integer references student, cname: varchar(40) references Class(name))
```

The query that I have written :

```
 select min(student.age),student.sname
 from student
 inner join enrolled 
 on enrolled.snum = student.snum or student.major = 'English' 
 inner join class 
 on  enrolled.cname = class.name  
 inner join faculty 
 on faculty.fid = class.fid and faculty.fname='Ivana Teach' 
 group by student.age 
 having student.age=min(student.age);
```

This gives an output :

| min(student.age) | sname |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | Maria White |
| 19 | Joseph Thompson |
| 20 | Christopher Garcia |
| 17 | Lisa Walker |
| 18 | Paul Hall |

Why am I getting such an answer where correct answer would be a single entry that is
17     Lisa Walker

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Don't re-add both the tags, Prakhar, they were both removed for a reason. Only tag the RDBMS you are really using.

Comment: *Why am I getting such an answer where correct answer would be a single entry* - well, either there's a bug in your query or a bug in the RDBMS..

Comment: Please share some sample data and mention the database name you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`group by student.age` will group by age, i.e. it will lead to results that show the minimum age of students *for each age group*, which is not what you intended, so this part should be removed.

`having student.age=min(student.age)` is also redundant.  The HAVING clause is used when you want to filter by some aggregated criteria.  For example (completely made-up), if you wanted to find students whose sum of all subject scores are greater than 100, you would do `group by student.sname having sum(student.scores) > 100`.  Again, that's not what you want in your particular query, so this part should be removed.

Regarding your inner joins:

```
inner join enrolled on enrolled.snum = student.snum or student.major = 'English' 
inner join class on  enrolled.cname = class.name  
inner join faculty on faculty.fid = class.fid and faculty.fname='Ivana Teach'
```

To find students whose major is English or enrolled in a course taught by Ivana Teach, you should use a WHERE clause instead, as follows:

```
inner join enrolled on enrolled.snum = student.snum  
inner join class on  enrolled.cname = class.name  
inner join faculty on faculty.fid = class.fid 
where (student.major = 'English' or faculty.fname='Ivana Teach')
```